# Submenus with different styles

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I have a menu with several sub-menus placed in between separators like so:

```
<Menu x:Name="mainMenu">

    <MenuItem x:Name="mainSubMenu" Header="Menus">

        <MenuItem x:Name="topMenuItem" Header="TopSubMenu">
        <MenuItem/>
        <MenuItem/>
        <MenuItem/>
    </MenuItem>

        <Separator/>

    <MenuItem x:Name="middleMenuItem" Header="MiddleSubMenu">
        <MenuItem Header="MI1"/>
        <MenuItem Header="MI2"/>
        <MenuItem Header="MI3"/>
        <MenuItem Header="MI4"/>
    </MenuItem>

    <Separator/>

        <MenuItem x:Name="bottomMenuItem" Header="Bottom" />
    </MenuItem>

</Menu>
```

I created a style for the middle sub-menu that allows to scroll through the different Menu Items. I want the top and bottom sub-menu to have the default style. How do I do that? How can I set different styles for the different sub-menus?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a style resource like:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="myStyleKey" TargetType="MenuItem">
            <!-- Your style definition goes here -->
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Menu x:Name="mainMenu">

            <MenuItem x:Name="mainSubMenu" Header="Menus">

                <MenuItem x:Name="topMenuItem" Header="TopSubMenu">
                    <MenuItem/>
                    <MenuItem/>
                    <MenuItem/>
                </MenuItem>

                <Separator/>

                <!-- Set style here -->
                <MenuItem Style="{StaticResource myStyleKey}" x:Name="middleMenuItem" Header="MiddleSubMenu">
                    <MenuItem Header="MI1"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="MI2"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="MI3"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="MI4"/>
                </MenuItem>

                <Separator/>

                <MenuItem x:Name="bottomMenuItem" Header="Bottom" />
            </MenuItem>

        </Menu>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

You can use this pattern for every menu item individually.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, give your Styles a Key and specify which style you want on each MenuItem by that key:

e.g.

```
     <Style x:Key="MyStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <blahblahblah/>
     </Style>

     <MenuItem Style="{StaticResource MyStyle1}">
```

HTH!

Janene